# CSS zoom property breaking Vuetify absolute positioned components

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, frontend

I am using zoom property on body

```
.body {
    zoom: 0.8
}
```

Its working fine, but some vuetify components use absolute position and it seems like they are getting off-course because VW and VH doesnt change with zoom.

I need to do this because clients have small screen, and my project isnt using REM, and at this point its so huge that its very hard to change, any suggestion? Thanks.

I tried window.ResizeTo(), or viewport-fit, but all with no sucesss.

Comment: `Its working fine` except in firefox, of course, which does not support this non-standard property - have you tried `transform:scale()`

Comment: @JaromandaX Tried transform, the whole page reduce and leaves empty spaces on all sides, if i change width and height to occupy again whole page, the same problem occurs, tooltips get misplaced, it looks that they dont suffer change, as if they are in the old unscaled position